# how to use Generics in functions and pattern matching in rust?

Tags: function, generics, rust

I'm solving a little math problem called the Syracuse problem (3n+1 problem).

Thing is i want my function to work for 2 types, one is u64 the other is a struct that extends the size of u64 by containing 2 u64 that i called U128.

my u64 function looks like this

```rust
fn syracuse(n: u64) -> u64 {
    match n % 2 {
        0 => n / 2,
        1 => 3 * n + 1,
        _ => 1,
    }
}
```

I've tried implementing a trait to my U128 and u64.

```rust
fn syracuse<T>(n: T) -> T where T : Add +Mul+Div+Rem + Basic0123 {
    match n % Basic0123::two() {
        Basic0123::zero() => n / Basic0123::two(),
        Basic0123::one() => Basic0123::three() * n + Basic0123::one(),
        _ => Basic0123::one(),
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile, the pattern matching doesn't like this. I'm new to rust and i'm trying to understand if creating a function with generic typing is okay for this problem that only treats 2 different types the DRY way or i should just stick with simply rewriting the function for the U128 type?

Comment: We're going to need more code than this. We don't have the definition of `Basic0123`, let alone its implementation; we don't have the definition of that `U128` type of yours, you haven't even told us what the error **actually is**!

Comment: If you would like some concrete help, please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) replicating your problem. This isn't just for clarity, a ton of problems get solved by changing the context of code from the problem you're facing, to a simplified version of the same problem

Comment: Finally, I'm not entirely sure why you implemented a `U128` yourself since [it exists in `std` since rust 1.26](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u128.html)

Comment: I didn't know u128 existsed in the std.
I'm quite new to rust and stack overflow, i take note to the lack of informations and will do my best the next time i ask a question. :)

Comment: It wasn't meant as a telling-off, just as pointers to let people help you faster and more effectively :-) for the integer types (and others), they're all under [data types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html). The main caveat is that pretty much everything exists up to 128-bit size except floats, for IEEE-related reasons

Comment: No worries, thank you for your fast answer, I got to understand how things work a bit more!

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to assume most of the stuff in the comments has been dealt with and you're back to using the `std::u128` primitive type rather than your own.

The proper way to implement the Syracuse conjecture on a generic type is as follows:

```
fn syracuse<T>(n: T) -> T
    where T : Copy + Eq + Add<Output = T> + Mul<Output = T> + Div<Output = T> + Rem<Output = T> + From<u32> {

    let zero:T = 0.into();
    match n % 2.into() == zero {
        true => n/(2.into()),
        false => n * (3.into()) + 1.into()
    }
}
```

In order of appearance:

- `Copy` is required because we did not require `Rem` on `&T`, but on `T`
- All the `Output` type specifications are so we do not implicitly change type - an operation on `T` will always map to `T`
- We are requiring `Eq` so we can compare the result of the remainder
- We are requiring `From<u32>` so we can `into()` every single numerical constant

A working version can be found [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67da13b80736c0ba674bab8356c1272a)